# hazelcast instance force-restart

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast community edition 3.6.2. In our cluster, network disconnect/reconnect is a natural event.
During split-brain operation, some cluster members are moving to `FROZEN` state and no matter what, I can't make them (programmatically) rejoin the cluster or even force them to shutdown.
Is there any way to force-restart the node and to make it try rejoining the other cluster members?

- Is there a graceful way to do that?
- Can someone provide a code sample?

Thanks

Comment: Hey @aviram, can you please open a github issue and share some logs to make it possible to investigate the actual problem?

Comment: submitted https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8246